# Iterating through separately-JSON-encoded strings found inside a document

Tags: python, json

I am having trouble iterating though json, containing nested json strings (with escaped quotes) in itself.

(My apologies in advance, I am sort of new and probably missing some important info...)

Actually I have several questions:

1) How can I iterate (as I tried to do below with nested for loops) through the elements beneath "section-content" of the section "nodes" (!not of the section "element-names"!)? My problem seems to be, that section-content is a string with escaped quotes, which represents a separate json string in itself.

2) Is the JSON example provided even valid json? I tried several validators, which all seem to fail when the escaped quotes come into play.

3) Is there a smarter method of accessing specific elements, instead of just iterating through the whole tree?
I am thinking of something that specifies key/value pairs like:

```
my_json_obj['sections']['section-id' = 'nodes']['section-content']['occ_id' = '051MZjd97jUdYfSEOG}k10']
```

Code:

```
import json
import requests
import pprint

client = requests.session()
header = {'X-CSRF-Token': 'Fetch', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
response = client.get('http://xxxxxx.xxx/ProcessManagement/BranchContentSet(BranchId=\'051MZjd97jUdYfX7{dREAm\',SiteId=\'\',SystemRole=\'D\')/$value',auth=('TestUser', 'TestPass'),headers=header)

my_json_obj = response.json()

sections = my_json_obj['sections']
for mysection in sections:
    print(mysection['section-id'])
    if mysection['section-id'] == 'NODES':
        nodes = mysection['section-content'] #nodes seems to be string 
        for mynode in nodes:
            print(mynode) #prints string character by character
```

JSON example:

```
{
  "smud-data-version": "0.1",
  "sections": [
    {
      "section-id": "ELEMENT-NAMES",
      "section-content-version": "",
      "section-content": "{\"D\":[
    {\"occ_id\":\"051MZjd97kcBgtZiEI0IvW\",\"lang\":\"E\",\"name\":\"0TD1 manuell\"},
    {\"occ_id\":\"051MZjd97kcBgtZiEH}IvW\",\"lang\":\"E\",\"name\":\"Documentation\"}
      ]}"
    },
    {
      "section-id": "NODES",
      "section-content-version": "1.0",
      "section-content": "[
        {\"occ_id\":\"051MZjd97jUdYfSEOG}k10\",\"obj_type\":\"ROOT\",\"reference\":\"\",\"deleted\":\"\",\"attributes\":[]},
        {\"occ_id\":\"051MZjd97jUdYfSEOH0k10\",\"obj_type\":\"ROOTGRP\",\"reference\":\"\",\"deleted\":\"\",\"attributes\":[]},
        {\"occ_id\":\"051MZjd97jcAnKoe03JRRm\",\"obj_type\":\"SCN\",\"reference\":\"\",\"deleted\":\"\",\"attributes\":[
            {\"attr_type\":\"NODE_CHANGED_AT\",\"lang\":\"\",\"values\":[\"20190213095843\"]},
            {\"attr_type\":\"NODE_CHANGED_BY\",\"lang\":\"\",\"values\":[\"TestUser\"]},
            {\"attr_type\":\"TCASSIGNMENTTYPE\",\"lang\":\"\",\"values\":[\"A\"]},
            {\"attr_type\":\"DESCRIPTION\",\"lang\":\"E\",\"values\":[\"Scenario\"]}
        ]}
    ]"
    }
  ]
}
```

Actual output:

```
ELEMENT-NAMES
NODES
[
{
"
o
c
c
_
i
d
"
```

Comment: Indeed, it looks like `section-content` has a second/separate layer of JSON encoding -- that's a very... err... *unusual* action on the part of the folks who generated it. Decode it with `json.loads()`, though, and there you are -- native Python data structure.

Comment: Indeed, it's not valid JSON. The literal newlines inside the quoted string would need to be `\n`s instead. Easiest thing to do is to just remove them outright, though.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy [Microsoft does this for some of their APIs, for example in OneDrive file handlers manifests](https://github.com/OneDrive/o365-markdown-file-handler-v2/blob/master/addin-schema-debug.json). [This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/file-handlers/define-actions?view=odsp-graph-online) says that it is "Due to limitations in the Azure Active Directory addIn extensions, these actions are stored serialized into a string".

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta, ...so they decided to turn their own technical debt into their end-users' problem? Typical.

Comment: @Charles Duffy:  I'm sorry, the literal newlines were added by me, in order to make the json more readable / add some sort of indentation that highlights the structure (even though it is inside a coded string).

Comment: @JHM, ahh. Please try to ensure that when you include data it remains usable for someone testing correctness of their answers, and at least notate loudly when you've made changes contrary to that end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully you can convince the folks who are generating this data to fix their server. That said, to work around the issues might look like:

```py
# instead of using requests.json(), remove literal newlines and then decode ourselves
# ...because the original data has newline literals in positions where they aren't allowed.
my_json_obj = json.loads(response.text.replace('\n', ''))

for section in my_json_obj['sections']:
    if section['section-id'] != 'NODES': continue
    # doing another json.loads() here so you treat content as an array, not a string
    for node in json.loads(section['section-content']):
        __import__('pprint').pprint(node)
```

...properly emits as output:

````
{u'attributes': [],
 u'deleted': u'',
 u'obj_type': u'ROOT',
 u'occ_id': u'051MZjd97jUdYfSEOG}k10',
 u'reference': u''}
{u'attributes': [],
 u'deleted': u'',
 u'obj_type': u'ROOTGRP',
 u'occ_id': u'051MZjd97jUdYfSEOH0k10',
 u'reference': u''}
{u'attributes': [{u'attr_type': u'NODE_CHANGED_AT',
                  u'lang': u'',
                  u'values': [u'20190213095843']},
                 {u'attr_type': u'NODE_CHANGED_BY',
                  u'lang': u'',
                  u'values': [u'TestUser']},
                 {u'attr_type': u'TCASSIGNMENTTYPE',
                  u'lang': u'',
                  u'values': [u'A']},
                 {u'attr_type': u'DESCRIPTION',
                  u'lang': u'E',
                  u'values': [u'Scenario']}],
 u'deleted': u'',
 u'obj_type': u'SCN',
 u'occ_id': u'051MZjd97jcAnKoe03JRRm',
 u'reference': u''}```
````